# Compactness and positive invariance of set under flow of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, dynamical-systems, control-theory, set-invariance

Given a system of ODEs, $$x'=y$$ $$y'=x-x^3-y$$ $$x(0)=x_0$$ $$y(0)=y_0,$$ also given a set $S=\{(x,y):V(x,y)\le k, x>0\}$, $V(x,y)=-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{y^2}{2}$, where $-\frac{1}{4}<k<0$, it is needed to be shown that $S$ is compact and positively invariant, and that if $(x_0, y_0)\in S$ then $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} (x(t), y(t))=(1,0).$

**My attempt:**

(i) **Compactness**: Consider $-\frac{1}{4}\le \frac{(x^2-1)^2+2y^2-1}{4}\le k$. Also, $S$ is closed. Therefore, $S$ is a compact set.

(ii) **Positive invariance**: I think we should use LaSalle's Invariance Principle in this case. Let $E:=\{(x,y)\in S: \dot{V}=0\}=\{(x,0)\}$. Also, consider $V(x, 0) = -\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{4}=-\frac{1}{4} < k$, which implies that $x=1$, $V^{-1}(-\frac{1}{4})=\{(x,0)\in S: V(x,y)=-\frac{1}{4}\}$. Hence, $\omega((x_0, y_0))\subseteq E\cup V^{-1}(-\frac{1}{4})=\{(1,0)\}$.

(iii) It follows from (ii) that $\forall \vec{x_0} \in \Omega$, $\psi_t(\vec{x_0})\to (1,0)$ as $t\to\infty$.

Please let me know if this is correct. I'm concerned about the choice of $-\frac{1}{4}$ - it seems rather arbitrary to me. Also, for the positive invariance, I'm not completely sure that I provided enough details to show it.

Comment: Well... Your attempt for (i) is offtopic since a proof that some set $S$ is compact should not rely on the differential system which motivated the definition of the set $S$. Your attempt for (ii) is a mystery as well since positive invariance of $S$ means that if $(x_0,y_0)$ is in $S$ then the whole trajectory stays in $S$. To show this, in 99% of the cases, one simply shows that, for every solution $(x(\ ),y(\ ))$, $t\mapsto V(x(t),y(t))$ is nonincreasing. Re your suggestion for (iii), I even fail to understand what you mean there... So, it seems you should be worried, not about details ...

Comment: ... of otherwise almost correct proofs, but about getting a basic understanding of the notions involved, how they are related, and what is being asked of you.

Comment: ((Additional note: 3 questions on exactly the same differential system, with basically the same underlying misconceptions, maybe these are enough?))

Comment: @Did: the course notes written for the course are laying out the  material very poorly. It's just very disorganized, so I basically have to decipher the concepts, which is almost like trying to translate from Chinese to English, without knowing Chinese.

Comment: The web is full of very good notes, available either as old fashioned downloadable textbook chapters, or as fancier web pages... If what you say of the notes you are using is true, drop them, they are only making you lose your time (and ours, if I may add). The present question is a good exhibit, since one basically has to *deconstruct* what you suggest before being able to turn to what the words mean and what a solution could be.

Comment: By the by, I would be curious to know what in your notes is forcing you, when asked about the compactness of some set $S$ explicitely defined as above, to start a "solution" by "$\dot V=\ldots$".

Comment: @Did: For the compactness - my mistake. I think it's easier to show it by considering $-\frac{1}{4}\le \frac{(x^2-1)^2+2y^2-1}{4}\le k$, which shows boundedness. SInce the set is closed, it is compact. The reason I used $\dot{V}$ to show compactness is because it is defining the set $S$.

Comment: For the invariance part, since we have $\dot{V}=-y^2$, where there is no $x$ present, it should be advisable to use LaSalle's Invariance Principle, which removes the mentioned restriction. LaSalle's Invariance Principle is used to find the limit sets (part iii dealing with (1,0) ).

Comment: LaSalle's Invariance Principle: unnecessary, as should be clear if only you read what I wrote. Why try to come back to big-name-theorems instead of trying to understand the mathematical situation...

Comment: @Did: What would you suggest to do for part iii? I appreciate your involvement. I think one has to find the limit set of $S$. Since $S$ is positively invariant and compact, it contains an equilibrium point or a periodic solution.

Comment: Well, the set $S$ is invariant (for some suitable $k$), hence one stays in $S$ forever, and there is a unique fixed point in $S$, namely $(x^*,y^*)=(1,0)$, and one knows that some sort of distance to $(x^*,y^*)$ measured by $U(x,y)=(x^2-1)^2+2y^2$ (yes, $U=4V+1$) is nonincreasing along the solutions, now what phenomena could happen? (Note: I do not like so much that you modify your comments after mine answering them are posted since this makes them look partly irrelevant, let me suggest to stop doing that. Likewise for the question itself.)

Comment: I think a trajectory would end up at $(1, 0)$. May I ask why did you define $U$ this way?

Comment: "think"? Can you *prove* it?

Comment: Since $V$ is decreasing and bounded, a trajectory $\psi_t((x,y))$ must end up at a limit set. We need to consider $\dot{V}=0$, which is where $y=0$. Since $V \ge -\frac{1}{4}$, consider $V(x, 0) = -\frac{1}{4}$. $x>0$ implies that $x=1$. Thus, the limit set $\omega_0 = \{(1,0)\}$.

Comment: Until "which is where $y=0$", you are fine. After that, no idea of the logic of the things you write.

Comment: $\dot{V} = -y^2 \le 0$, hence for $\dot{V} = 0$, $y=0$. Since $V$ is decreasing and $V(x,y)=-\frac{1}{4}$ is the lowest bound of $S$, we can consider $V(x,0)=-\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: ?? No, the fact that $t\mapsto V(x(t),y(t))$ is nonincreasing does not imply that $V(x(t),y(t))\to\min V$ (if this is what you are trying to use). A priori, $V(x(t),y(t))$  could converge to any limit $\ell\geqslant\min V=-\frac14$ (and such that $\ell\leqslant V(x_0,y_0)$).

Comment: Since $y=0$, we plug this into the system and get $x' = 0$, $y' = x-x^3 = 0$. Since $x>0$, $x=1$.

Comment: Well yes, if you *assume* that the trajectory converges to a fixed point, then there is not much to do... But the whole point is that one is supposed to *prove* this.

Comment: There's a corollary from the Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem in the notes which states that if $S$ is a positively invariant compact set of a differential system, then $S$ contains an equilibrium point or a periodic solution of the system. One can check that $\nabla\cdot f(x,y) = -1 < 0$ and does not change sign on $S$, thus the system has no periodic solutions, hence it must have an equilibrium point. Now, since $(1,0)$ is a center point of the system, it is stable, and thus a trajectory must converge to it.

Comment: If you can state this result precisely (at the moment, the notations $f$ and $\nabla\cdot f$ are in need of explanations) and show that it applies to your setting, then you have an answer. Perhaps post your try as an answer and then we will have something solid to discuss.

Comment: Just posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x,y):=\begin{bmatrix}
y \\ x-x^3-y
\end{bmatrix}$

A corollary to the Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem states:

> If $S$ is a positively invariant compact set of a differential system $\vec{x}'=f(\vec{x})$, then $S$ contains an equilibrium point or a periodic solution to the system.

One can check that the divergence of $f$, namely $\nabla\cdot f(x,y)=−1<0$ does not change sign on $S$, thus the system has no periodic solutions, hence it must have an equilibrium point. Now, since $\dot{V}=-y^2\le 0$, $y=0$. We can substitute $y=0$ into the system and get that $x-x^3=0$. Since $x>0$, $x=1$. In addition, it can be checked that $(1,0)$ is a center point of the system, thus it is stable, and thus a trajectory $\psi_t(\vec{x_0})$ must converge to $(1,0)$.